# Earlier graphviz rank

Tags: graphviz

In the following graph, is there an attribute I can set that would render A and H on the same rank; and D and G on the same rank? For my use case, each node is a process that will begin as soon as the incoming node processes have completed and I would like the position of the node to indicate the start time.

```
digraph {
    A -> B
    B -> C
    H -> C
    C -> D
    D -> E
    E -> F
    C -> G
    G -> F
}
```

[image: digraph]

I would like the result to look like the following, but as these graphs are dynamically generated, I do not want to have to calculate which nodes I should be marking as the same rank.

```
digraph {
    { rank="same"; A; H }
    { rank="same"; D; G }
    A -> B
    B -> C
    H -> C
    C -> D
    D -> E
    E -> F
    C -> G
    G -> F
}
```

[image: digraph-ideal]

Comment: Does [`rankdir="BT"`](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:rankdir) works?

Comment: No, that provides a vertical flip of the first image. The ranks remain unchanged: H is beside B and G is beside E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for exists as a setting in Flying Logic software and is called bias there.

Unfortunately, at the time of my answer (March 2021) this doesn't exist. Please see the answer from one of the long-time maintainers to my question on twitter. https://twitter.com/Graphviz/status/1128339044826517508?s=20

Answer (score 1):

The semi-recently added attribute TBbalance does what you ask, see https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/TBbalance/

add this line to your graph [TBbalance=min] and you get
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This gvpr (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) program seems to correctly add subgraphs w/ rank=same to "raise" nodes as requested.
Note, don't expect it to work if the source graph has subgraphs (especially clusters).

```
BEGIN {
  int i, j, n, s=0, changed=0; 
  int checkedNode[];
  int newRank[];
  string str1, rankString[], fld[int];
  node_t aNode, headNode;
  edge_t anEdge;
  graph_t aSub;
}
BEG_G{
  for (aNode=fstnode($G); aNode; aNode = nxtnode(aNode)){
    if (aNode.indegree==0){
      newRank[aNode]=1;
    }
  }
  while (1){
  for (newRank[aNode]){
    for (anEdge = fstout(aNode); anEdge; anEdge = nxtout(anEdge)){
      headNode=anEdge.head;
      if (newRank[headNode]=="" || (newRank[aNode]+1)>newRank[headNode]){
        newRank[headNode]=newRank[aNode]+1;
        print ("// rank=", newRank[headNode], "  ",  headNode.name);
    changed++;
      }
    }
  }
  if (changed==0)break;
  changed=0;
  }
  for (newRank[aNode]){
    rankString[newRank[aNode]]=sprintf("%s%s|",rankString[newRank[aNode]],aNode.name);
  }
  /* create subgraphs w/ rank=same */
  for (rankString[i]){
    unset(fld);
    n=tokens(rankString[i],fld,"|");
    if (n>1){
      str1=sprintf("__sub_%d",++s);    
      aSub=subg($G,str1);
      aSub.rank="same";
      for (j=0;j<n;j++){
        print ("// fld: >", fld[j], "<  ", j, "  ", n);
        aNode=node($G, fld[j]);
        aNode=subnode(aSub, aNode);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Use command line like this:

```
gvpr -c -f raiseRanks.gvpr  yourfile.gv | dot -Tpng >yourfile.png
```

Giving:

```
// comments deleted
igraph {
        subgraph __sub_1 {
                graph [rank=same];
                A;
                H;
        }
        subgraph __sub_2 {
                graph [rank=same];
                D;
                G;
        }
        A -> B;
        B -> C;
        C -> D;
        C -> G;
        H -> C;
        D -> E;
        E -> F;
        G -> F;
}
```

[image]